# Converting Vanilla ES6 to work with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a website, which was built with Jekyll and Gulp. I'm attempting to transition it over to React, using styled components via [next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

My problem is importing all my original js, and creating components out of the modules.

Here's an example. I have this module, written in es6, how do I render this via React?

```
const Universe = () => {
const randomNum = (low, high) => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
  return r;
};

const shootingStars = name => {
  const stars = document.querySelectorAll(name);
  const starsArray = [...stars];
  setInterval(() => {
    starsArray.forEach(el => {
        el.style.cssText = `transform: rotate(${randomNum(
          0,
          180
        )}deg) translateY(${randomNum(0, 200)}px)`;
      });
    }, 9000);
  };
  shootingStars('.shooting-star');
  shootingStars('.shooting-star-right');
};

export default Universe;
```

Here's what my index.js file looks like:

```
import SiteHeader from '../components/header/Header';
import Universe from '../components/universe/ShootingStars';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <SiteHeader />
    <div className="shooting-star" />
    <div className="shooting-star-right" />
    <Universe />
  </div>
);
```

I'm getting `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. I hope this is enough information. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please make an attempt at using React and then post more specific questions related to the issues you're having.

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation with document.querySelectorAll and document.getElementById instead use ref for getting DOM elements. Also if you're rendering this server side, there will be no "document" object. Try wrapping in if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {}